# Irrationals and Density

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation, irrational-numbers

How do I prove the following?

$[{x,y \epsilon \mathbb{R}: x < y}]$

Prove that there is an irrational number u between x and y,

s.t. x < u < y, where x and y are any two real numbers.

Apply the density of $[\mathbb{Q} to \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} and \frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}]$

I believe  this is similar to the Archimedean principle.  So , square root 2 and 1 over square root 2 are both irrational . I believe,  I have to incorporate the well ordering property of $\mathbb{N}$ , but I'm getting lost in showing this.

Comment: Notice that $x/\sqrt{2} < r < y/\sqrt{2}$ if and only if $x < r \sqrt{2} < y$.  Can you show that if $r$ is rational, $r \sqrt{2}$ is irrational?  Can you use the density of $\Bbb{Q}$ to establish the existence of a rational $r$ satisfying the first inequality I wrote?

Comment: Since y>x, then y-x>0, using the Archimedean property, there exists a n in the set of natural numbers s.t. ny>nx -> n(y-x) >1 -> nx+1 <ny. Since, nx >0, there exists a m in the set of natural numbers s.t. nx < m, then m-1 <= nx < m. Also,  m<= nx + 1 < m+1, so we move things around... m <= nx+1 < ny, then nx < m <ny, we divide by n to get:  x < m/n < y and set m/n to x/sqrt2 and y/sqrt2. Is that sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle t = \frac{x + y}{2}$.

If $t$ is irrational, set $t = u$, and you are done.

Therefore, without loss of generality, $~t~$ is rational.

If $x$ is irrational, then 
set $~\displaystyle u = \frac{t + x}{2} \implies u~$ is irrational.

Further, then, $x < u < t < y.$

---

Therefore, without loss of generality, $x,t$ are both rational.

Let $s = t-x,~$ and set $\displaystyle ~u = t - \frac{s\sqrt{2}}{2} \implies u~$ is irrational.

Then $x = t - s < u < t < y.$

Comment: Sorry I'm very old and learning it in steps, this is very quick for me. Why do you take the midpoint? Is that considered the least element? I thought we are using Archimedean and that rational numbers are dense in real numbers principle?

Comment: @Christopher1965 The stated problem is to prove that there exists (at least) one irrational between $x$ and $y$.  The midpoint is a convenient number that is, by definition, between $x$ and $y$.  I am proving the stated problem in the easiest and simplest way possible.  There is no reason to bring Archimedes or density into the analysis, in order to prove the stated problem.

Comment: thank you @user2661923, if I brought in density and Archimedes, could I follow page 28 in the Basic Analysis: Introduction to Real Analysis by Jiri Lebl book, stopping before it says Corollary 1.2.5. The link is here: https://www.jirka.org/ra/realanal.pdf

Comment: @Christopher1965 I am not familiar with that material.  It would not do any good for me to examine the pdf file, because I would have to study the subject for several months before I felt qualified to express a reliable opinion on any part of it.